# inside main circuit breaker panel; what are these elements good for?

Tags: circuit-breaker, panel

[image]

Can anyone explain what does that TeleLE circuit breaker do in there ? Also that circuit breaker looking element with only one small black square button on it please.

Comment: Did you look for the datasheet for the device? It would explain its function.

Comment: @Transistor No, I could not find it

Comment: Where on the planet? Not my region by appearance, but I'd guess the item with the reset button is what I'd call a whole-house GFCI, but I think it's called an RCD globally. Looks for imbalance in current due to leakage and shuts off at a level of imbalance (IIRC 30ma for this type) - our single-circuit versions trip at 5ma, which is safer for people, but too sensitive for whole-house.

Comment: Looks like relay. C1 and C2 coil, 14 and 12 contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Shunt trip breaker add-on

This is [GE's "Redline" series](https://www.netrauta.fi/attachments/products/ge/johdonsuoja_g/johdonsuoja_g_esite.pdf) of miniature circuit breaker products.

The "Tele LE" device isn't in this catalog, but a "Tele L" device is. (page C.8)  There are other "Tele Lx" with a second character, and those indicate terminal type (lug, ring, etc.)  It is designed to bolt onto a Red Line circuit breaker and provide **Shunt Trip** for that breaker.  That means if you apply momentary current to lines C1 and 14, it trips the attached breaker.

Shunt trips are used to provide auxiliary ways of safety-tripping a circuit breaker.  For instance, at a "Maker faire" once, I saw an "phone app" with auxiliary hardware which would tell you if you left your oven on. A nice feature would be a "trip my breaker" button on the app, which would tell the hardware to send a 24V pulse to a Shunt Trip breaker in the panel.  Great application for shunt trip.

To reset a shunt-trip breaker, you have to flat-foot back to the panel and reset it by hand.  (there are good reasons for not allowing remote/automated reset!!!!)

The other terminals are an auxiliary contact tied to the breaker handle, so the position of the breaker handle can be remotely sensed.

### Mystery gadget

The Tele L is 1 unit wide, so it doesn't account for the mystery gadget on the right, which is clearly *not* a member of GE's Red Line.  Since its label is gone, it may be illegal to have it in the panel. The button adds mystery but it's not an RCD (GFCI) tripper for this breaker - the breaker is already RCD (note the TEST button).  Obviously the sticker told the tale.

But here's a thought.  Shunt trip breakers typically use low voltage for the shunt trip coil, such as 24-60VAC for the Tele L.  It's plausible that thing is a **transformer** to create that low voltage supply.

GE's Red Line includes a number of transformers to fill the bill, all 2 modules wide (link, p. D.29) That might be why they weren't used.